# Is it possible to extend the "New" context menu?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to add menu item in "New" context menu(package explorer)? I tried something like this, but the the menu item isn't placed in the context menu, but above it.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus"> 
 <viewerContribution 
   id="org.eclipse.ui.articles.action.contribution.popup.navigator"
targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer"> 
<action
     id="org.eclipse.ui.articles.action.contribution.navigator.action1" 
     label="View Action 1"
     icon="icons/red_dot.gif"
     menubarPath="group.new" 
     class="org.eclipse.ui.articles.action.contribution.ViewAction1Delegate"
  enablesFor="!">
  </action>
   </viewerContribution> 
</extension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only by using the org.eclipse.ui.newWizards extension point.  Otherwise it's probably not the right context menu to use.